# Making slideshow which will automatically change images

Tags: java, swing, slideshow

I have problem with program in kind of slideshow. I add two arguments for this program: path to folder which include images, time after images will be repainting.
Images should draw in original size and the window adjust to that size. If some files won't be image, program should draw "ERROR" statement. Anyway, that program haven't work at all and it haven't draw any image. Anyone could tell me why it doesn't draw anything and whether Timer is good way to repaint images?

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel
{

        Image img;

        private int period;
        private int n = 0;
        private File[] files;
        Timer timer;
        Dimension d;

      public ImagePanel(File dir, int period) 
      {
          this.period = period;

          files = dir.listFiles();
          loadImage(files[n++].getPath());

          timer = new Timer(period, new ActionListener()
              {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        //Component component = (Component) e.getSource();
                        //JFrame f = (JFrame) 
                        //SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(component);
                        //f.pack();
                        if (n < files.length)
                        {
                            loadImage(files[n].getPath());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            repaint();
                            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                        }
                        n++;
                    }
              });

          timer.start();
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
      {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (img != null)
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
      }

      private void loadImage(String imgFileName) 
      {
        img = new ImageIcon(imgFileName).getImage();
        int w = img.getWidth(this);
        int h = img.getHeight(this);
        if (w != -1 && w != 0 && h != -1 && h != 0) 
        {
          d = new Dimension(img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this));
        }

        revalidate();
        repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize()
      {
          return new Dimension(img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this));
      }


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new File(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]) * 1000);
    frame.add(panel);
    //frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

 }
}
```

Comment: *"path to folder which include images, ... If some files won't be image, program should draw "ERROR" statement. `paths = dir.list();`"* Better to use `File.list(java.io.FilenameFilter)` with a `FilenameFilter` based around the array returned from `ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whether Timer is good way to repaint images?

Yes, you should use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation.

> Anyone could tell me why it doesn't draw anything

In your `ImagePanel` class you should create a method like `setImage(...)`. This method will be invoked by the Timer code whenever you want to change the image.

Then in the `setImage(...)` method you need to invoke `repaint()` to tell the panel to repaint itself.

Comment: camickr, I think that my LoadImage is sth like the setImage method, isn't it? I added repaint, but it still don't work :(

Comment: @MichałBartoś, so do some basic debugging. Does the paintComponent() method execute? Does the loadImage() method get invoked? Is the image null? Is the image loaded? We can't tell what problems you are having.

Comment: I'm nearly to solve it. I changed: String[] myList = dir.list(); on Files[] files = dir.listFiles(); Could you tell me what is difference between e.g. myList[0]; and files[0].getPath() ? Second one is working, but the first nope. The list() method doesn't return paths to files? And the last problem: images is showing in tiny window (probably 5x20px) - setPreferredSize() couldn't change size of the window after each Timer step?

Comment: @MichałBartoś,  `what is difference` - you tell me. Did you display the toString() representation of each object to see what the actual filename is? `setPreferredSize() couldn't change size of the window after each Timer step?` - the frame size won't change just because you change the size of a component on the frame. You need to pack() the frame. Personally I don't think this is a good idea. Just keep the frame size fixed. The panel should be added to a JScrollPane in case the image is too large to display. Let the user control the frame size, not your application.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You have right, probably it's strange idea to change frame size dynamically, but I just want try to do it. I packed the JFrame at the start (you can see my class Browser which extends JFrame above).

Comment: @MichałBartoś, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Not exactly I forgot to add to my previous comment that although I've added pack() to JFrame, it still doesn't adjust frame size to image size. It only take tiny size of the first string 'ERROR' :/

Comment: @MichałBartoś, The job of the paintComponent() method is to simply paint the image if it is not null. There is no need for any other logic, If you want error processing then display a JOptionPane when you attempt to load the image. Error logic should NOT be in the painting method. You also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the class to return the size of the image. Then when you pack the frame the size of the panel will be the size of the image.

Comment: Sorry, but I still struggle with that. I overridden the getPreferredSize(), but it takes size of my the first image and isn't adjust its' values to size of the next images. There is any way to update returned Dimension? I put there return new Dimension(img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this)); and img object is changing in time, but window isn't adjusted.

Comment: @MichałBartoś, I gave you the steps. I haven't seen your updated [mcve] demonstrating the problem so I can't tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my post. I still have some logic in paintComponent(), because at the moment my purpose is to fix auto resizing of the window. I also found sth like revalidate(); but it also didn't affect on window size.

Comment: @MichałBartoś `I still have some logic in paintComponent(), because at the moment my purpose is to fix auto resizing of the window` - so get rid of all the unnecessary code. The point of the [mcve] is to isolate the code directly related to the problem. We don't want to look at unnecessary or commented out code. Why do you have a "loaded" variable? If the image is not null it is loaded. Again simple code. I still don't see a pack() statement anywhere? The frame doesn't resize automatically. I don't have time to keep making the same suggestion over and over.

Comment: For the `MCVE` all the code should be in one class so we can copy paste a single class if we want to testt. So the ImagePanel becomes the main class. Then you simply add a main() method that builds the frame and add the ImagePanel to the frame.

Comment: I removed commented code and put it into one class. Loaded variable I had just because if the image is null, I want print statement in window size 200x200 and I had if statement in getPreferredSize() which depends of this variable. I'm so sorry I waste your time so long, I hope that updated code is already clear. Before I had pack() in Browser class, now I added it to main() -  frame.pack();

Comment: @MichałBartoś, 1) the updated code doesn't even compile, so how did you test it??? 2) You said you want the frame to resize with every image, so the frame needs to be packed every time the image changes. See `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent()` you can use this method in the Timer after the image is loaded to access the Window to be packed 3) don't set the preferred size. That is the job of the getPreferredSize() method.

Comment: Thank you a lot - it really works! Again, I'm really cause I give you a lot of trouble with simply showing my needs etc. You are so helpful, good luck in your job. :)